# Material Design Select option within a Select Dropdown

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I want to use [select dropdown](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/demo/material.components.select) of the AngularJs Material Design library inside a select dropdown. The problem I face is When i select the inner dropdown the list is displayed Outside the content .

```
 <md-select placeholder="Pick" ng-model="someVal">
     <md-option value="1">Profile</md-option>
     <md-select placeholder="Pick" ng-model="someVal">
        <md-option value="3">sub header</md-option>
     </md-select>
     <md-option value="7">LogOut</md-option>
 </md-select>
```

here i if i want to place another Select dropdown within the parent Dropdown , instance like the code above ?

When i click the sub select the list is displayed out of the content box. Here is an example from codepen demonstrating the issue:

http://codepen.io/sstorie/pen/vOyGga

Answer (score 0):

You have a select inside a select. You can't do that.
You can have 2 selects.